# How can I add items to a layout in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am developing an application in Qt 4.8.4, in which I do the following:

I subclass QGridLayout as follows:

```
class Viewer : public QGridLayout
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...................
private:
    // Objects
    /// Maximize button object
    ViewerGeneric* viewerGeneric;

    /// Maximize button object
    QPushButton* btnMaximize;

    /// Close button object
    QPushButton* btnClose;

    /// Connect button object
    QPushButton* btnConnect;

    /// Central viewer layout object
    QGridLayout* viewer;

    /// Indicates the row position in the main grid
    unsigned int row;

    /// Indicates the column position in the main grid
    unsigned int col;
};
```

Then in the constructor I do something like this:

```
// Create the objects
btnMaximize = new QPushButton("max");
btnClose = new QPushButton("close");
btnConnect = new QPushButton("connect");

// Add the horizontal toolbar
QHBoxLayout* toolbar = new QHBoxLayout();
toolbar->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinimumSize);
toolbar->addItem(new QSpacerItem(0, 0, 
                     QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum));
toolbar->addWidget(btnMaximize);
toolbar->addWidget(btnClose);

// Add the 'Connect' button
viewer = new QGridLayout();
viewer->addWidget(btnConnect);

// Add the widgets
this->addItem(toolbar, 0, 0);
this->addItem(viewer, 0, 0, 2);
```

But, in the end, when I show the Viewer class in my main window the window is **completely blank**! Hope anybody can help me. Thank you.

Cheers,

Comment: Yes, for sure, maybe I should try to the same there and look up the generated code.

Comment: The comment above about Qt Designer is outdated and doesn't point to the correct Qt site anyway. I believe the functionality of Qt Designer has been incorporated into [Qt Creator](https://www.qt.io/ide/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution:

For adding layouts into layouts, use addLayout() function instead of addItem(). I do not really know which is the difference but it works.

Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 4):

If parent widget is already visible, you need to call `show()` method of the later added widgets to make them visible.

Comment: Dear hyde, if I do that the added widgets appear in another windows!

Comment: @DídacPérez Then you're doing something wrong with the code that adds the widgets later. If widget is it's own window, it means it has no parent, and adding it to layout sets the parent. Are you by any chance adding them to a new layout, instead of the layout of the correct parent widget? Please add that code to the question!

Answer (score 0):

You can add it using addWidget function i suppose... I have not worked with it yet... you can try it...

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html

refer to the above page for more info...

Answer (score 0):

Set they layout to the parent first and then use the addWidget function to add widgets to it.

If you want, you can use the show() and hide() functions to avoid flickering and show everything in the layout at once.

If you don't need to add widgets dynamically you should try to use the QT designer and an create an .ui class